# Find the unit normal of a solid ball of radius $r$ centred at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis

How would I find the unit normal $n(x)$ of a solid ball of radius $r$ centered at $(0,0,0)$, that points out of the the solid ball at $x$?

Comment: Here it's a very special case. Since it's a unit ball, $n(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

For a ball of radius $R > 0$ centered at $x_{0}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{N}$, the unit normal at a boundary point $x$, a.k.a., the unique unit vector at $x$ that points directly away from the center, is
$$
n(x) = \frac{x - x_{0}}{R}.
$$

Comment: what will be the unit normal vector if my domain of definition is  $\mathbf R^{N}-B(0,\epsilon)$ instead of $B(0,\epsilon)$

Comment: @bunny: The stated vector is the unique unique normal pointing into your domain; to get the unit normal pointing away from the domain, multiply by $-1$.

Comment: but above you were saying that the unit normal vector in the direction away from the center is given by the above formula, so unit vector away from the center should mean that unit vector away from the domain right?

Comment: @bunny: For a ball, yes, pointing away from the center is the same as pointing as pointing away from (i.e., toward the exterior of) the domain. For the complement of a ball, "away from the domain" means _toward_ the center of the ball. If this isn't clear, a sketch of the complement of a disk in the plane should help.

Comment: ok i got it now @Andrew D. Hwang. Thanks for the help